# Generate a matrix of combinations (permutation) without repetition (array exceeds maximum array size preference)

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, permutation

I am trying to generate a matrix, that has all unique combinations of [0 0 1 1], I wrote this code for this:

```
v1 = [0 0 1 1];
M1 = unique(perms([0 0 1 1]),'rows');
```

• This isn't ideal, because *perms()* is seeing each vector element as unique and doing:

`4! = 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 = 24` combinations.

• With *unique()* I tried to delete all the repetitive entries so I end up with the combination matrix M1 →

only `[4!/ 2! * (4-2)!] = 6` combinations!

Now, when I try to do something very simple like:

```
n = 15;
i = 1;
v1 = [zeros(1,n-i) ones(1,i)];
M = unique(perms(vec_1),'rows');
```

• Instead of getting `[15!/ 1! * (15-1)!] = 15` combinations, the *perms()* function is trying to do

`15! = 1.3077e+12` combinations and it's interrupted.

• How would you go about doing in a much better way? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, indeed. First perms needs yo output before unique is called, so your code does not fix the memory issue.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. What would you suggest to do? Is there a way to generate those combinations without running out of memory?

Comment: I assume writing it yourself, the code. Not sure if there is an inbuilt

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that, I know the math around it and how to calculate the combination's degree with the binomial coefficient, but it's not obvious how the function perms is working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `nchoosek` to return the indicies which should be `1`, I think in your heart you knew this must be possible because you were using the definition of `nchoosek` to determine the expected final number of permutations! So we can use:

```
idx = nchoosek( 1:N, k );
```

Where N is the number of elements in your array `v1`, and `k` is the number of elements which have the value `1`. Then it's simply a case of creating the `zeros` array and populating the ones.

```
v1 = [0, 0, 1, 1];
N = numel(v1); % number of elements in array
k = nnz(v1);   % number of non-zero elements in array

colidx = nchoosek( 1:N, k );                  % column index for ones
rowidx = repmat( 1:size(colidx,1), k, 1 ).';  % row index for ones

M = zeros( size(colidx,1), N ); % create output
M( rowidx(:) + size(M,1) * (colidx(:)-1) ) = 1;
```

This works for both of your examples without the need for a huge intermediate matrix.

---

Aside: since you'd have the indicies using this approach, you could instead create a `sparse` matrix, but whether that's a good idea or not would depend what you're doing after this point.

Comment: I must say, I didn't really get the last two lines you wrote, but it worked in my code and it only took ~0.09s, so thank you very much! I'm doing a hamming code project and I need to come up with an idea to generate the error matrix. So this worked just fine! I also used nchoosek() in my code before

Comment: @johnny_1010 The last line uses [linear indexing](https://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/02/08/linear-indexing/) to fill the matrix entries specified by `rowidx` and `colidx`